# Why subtracted-memory address number is smaller than expected?

Tags: c, memory-address

```
typedef struct list {
   struct list* next;
   struct list* prev;
}list_t;

typedef struct node {
   int value;
   int key;
   list_t list;
}node_t;


int main(void)
{
    node_t alpha;
    alpha.key = 10;
    alpha.value = 11;

    printf("&alpha.list address : %p - &alpha.key address : %p  =  %p", &alpha.list, &alpha.key, &alpha.list - &alpha.key);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
&alpha.list address : 0096F994 - &alpha.key address : 0096F990  =  00000000
```

why subtracted memory address number is smaller than expect?
how do i get exact subtracted number?

Comment: What value do you expect?

Comment: Oh i expected 4 (0096F994 - 0096F990) not 0

Comment: sonjuan, For fun, what do you now expect from `&alpha.key - &alpha.value`? 1, 4 or something else?

Comment: what does your compiler spit out as warnings? the cofe isnt legal C

Comment: you're using an invalid conversion specifier for printing the difference too, it isnt a pointer

Answer (score 4):

Code is subtracting dissimilar pointer types.  that gives me a compiler error.  For OP, who knows what a non-compliant compiler might do?

```
error: invalid operands to binary - (have 'list_t *' {aka 'struct list *'} and 'int *')
```

As pointers are of different types, recommend to convert to a common `char*` first.  Recall pointer subtraction, the difference is in units of the referenced type, `char` in the below case.

```
printf("%td\n", (char *)&alpha.list - (char *)&alpha.key);
```

When two pointers are subtracted,  "....The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t`." C17dr § 6.5.6 9

Use `"%td"` to print that difference.

If your compiler is old and lacks `"%td"`, cast to a wide available type.

```
// Alternative for old compilers. (pre-C99)
printf("%ld\n", (long) ((char *)&alpha.list - (char *)&alpha.key));
```

---

Deeper

Subtracting pointers that are not part of the same array (or 1 past), even though both are address on a common structure is troublesome code.

Consider using `offsetof(type, member-designator)` (which returns a `size_t`) to find  offsets.

```
printf("%zu\n", offsetof(node_t , list));
printf("%zu\n", offsetof(node_t , key));
// 8
// 4
```

Answer (score -1):

I think where you're getting into trouble is with your types. %p is intended to print pointers, but the result of pointer subtraction is an int. Also, I belive that doing subtraction on different pointer types (e.g., `struct list *` and an `int *`) is probably undefined... meaning absolutely anything could happen. `gcc` throws an error if you try it.

I get a correct result if I do:

`printf("%p - %p = %ld\n", &alpha.list, &alpha.key, (void*)&alpha.list - (void*)&alpha.key);`

**EDIT, to address one of the comments**

According to section 5.7 of the spec, subtraction of "incompatible pointer types" is undefined, so any result is possible, and it should absolutely not be counted upon to behave in any predictable fashion. As for the result of pointer subtraction, the result is a `ptrdiff_t`. According to section 17.2.4, paragraph 2: "The type ptrdiff_­t is an implementation-defined signed integer type that can hold the difference of two subscripts in an array object..." Yes, `void*` is undefined (new to more recent versions of the C spec, btw), so I've learned something there. Use any other byte-sized pointer instead.

The restriction that says you have to do ptr subtraction on pointers from the same array is there to prevent the unpredictable behavior that would result in doing math on addresses from different page allocations. If two addresses (of different types) are from the same allocation, the math will work as expected.

Compiling the code as it exists in the question, with gcc 9.3.0, gives:

`error: invalid operands to binary - (have 'list_t *' {aka 'struct list*'} and 'int *')`

Switching to the void* (or any other byte-size pointer) cast to avoid the compiler's complaint about the types of the pointers gives a warning that underscore the defined int-ness of pointer subtraction:

`format '%p' expects argument of type 'void *', but argument has type 'long int'`

Comment: Note that subtracting two `void*` is UB and the resulting difference is not certainly a `long`.

Comment: you need to cast to char*, and the difference is a ptrdiff_t, not int